# Continue/Abort git revert a while after it was initiated

Tags: git, github, revert

A few days ago a team member tried a git revert on a git repo on our server. Since then, changes have been pushed to and pulled from the repo, and I'm wondering how to resolve the message I get when running `git status`

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
You are currently reverting commit 1324625.
(all conflicts fixed: run "git revert --continue")
(use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Basically, the way everything is working right now is how it should be, and I don't want to choose one of these options and mess it up.

So, what should I do?

Comment: (a) make a copy of your repository so that you can be confident about not losing anything (b) run `git revert --abort` and verify that you have achieved your goal.  If (b) doesn't work, come back here and let us know how the results differ from what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to decide how to proceed from here one would need to understand the goal state.

Why was the revert attempted?  Why was it never completed?  Is it still desired to undo those changes?  Or have other changes made it unnecessary/undesired?  Or was it a mistake in the first place?  Or...?

If you know that the last *committed* state is what you want, then you'll end up wanting to `--abort`.

If you know that your local working copy is what you want, then you probably want to '--continue' (because the revert changes are likely in the index and working tree).

If you need to see what the difference would be, use `git status`; the revert changes should show as staged.

If you really can't tell what's the right outcome, the "safer" option is to `--continue`; this will create one or more new commits.  *Before pushing* you can test the state with the new commits, then if it turns out you don't want them you can back them out (with `git reset --hard`).

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Per larsks request, I went ahead and made a copy of my repository and ran `git revert --abort` to get rid of the message. After some testing, I've concluded that nothing was lost and all works the way it should.

```
git revert --abort
```

got rid of that message with no consequences for me. That being said, its never a bad idea to back up your repo anyway ;)

Comment: It is not "with no consequences".  It is "with no consequences that were negative for you in this instance".  The consequence is that the staged changes associated with the revert operation (the inverse of the changes made by the commit(s) that were reverted, as adjusted for conflict resolution) are discarded.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, mark. I edited my answer to reflect on your point.